# How to handle event side effects?

Tags: javascript, cyclejs

I'm trying to implement a dropzone such as [this React Component](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone/blob/master/src/index.js). However, I'm a bit stuck on how to apply write effects on events, e.g.

```
dragOver$: DOM
  .select('#dropzone')
  .events('ondragover')
  .map(e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'
  })
```

Which won't work since there is no sink. The code inside `map` should really be performed inside a sink.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a simple driver that will handle this. See the docs on drivers [here](http://cycle.js.org/drivers.html).

It seems like you could do something like this:

```
function main(sources) {
  return {
    dragOver: DOM.select('#dropzone').events('ondragover')
  };
}

const drivers = {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app'),
  dragOver: (e$ => e$.subscribe(e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'
  }))
}
```

In short: drivers encapsulate all side effects and return inputs from those interfaces, and all side effects in Rx code is constrained to the `subscribe` argument Observers.

Comment: There is also an example of a preventDefault driver used here: https://github.com/cyclejs/cycle-examples/blob/master/autocomplete-search/src/main.js#L294